# Avoid Load and re-Train of a Neural Network Model

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I built a feedforward neural network, his goal is to classify a target value, the train has to be defined for n-days.

The input is constituted by 12 neurons (since I have 12 different data each of which for each day has around 25000 values [25000 x 1]). The network, for every single day, manages 12 * 25000 input values. (The data are all numeric)

Since I have to train for about 741 different days (This implies I have to perform a train with 741 * 12 * 25000 data), at the moment I'm able to train only for a single day, save the model and reload it to train for the subsequence day.

There is a way to avoid this save - load model procedure and train for all the 741 days at once? Should I have to use a particular data generator?

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: check [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27359/how-to-train-data-by-batch-from-disk) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828616/streaming-large-training-and-test-files-into-tensorflows-dnnclassifier) and see if that helps. If not please provide more details for your specific needs